# Invalid object name 'Properties' Exception when executing agent experienceAnalytics/reduce/agent

Tags: xdb

We are getting the following error message in our Sitecore log file.  We can not tell if this is breaking anything though, as the site appears to work as expected.

This is occurring after an upgrade from 7.2 to 8.1 U3.

```
8608 19:42:09 ERROR Exception when executing agent experienceAnalytics/reduce/agent
Exception: System.Exception
Message: Invalid object name 'Properties'.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderReader..ctor(DataProviderCommand command)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.<>c__DisplayClass12.<CreateReader>b__10()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func 1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.CreateReader(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProviderProperties.GetProperties()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProviderProperties.get_Item(String key)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Reduce.TimestampStore.get_LastRun()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Reduce.ReduceAgent.IsDue()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Reduce.ReduceAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Data.DataException
Message: Error executing SQL command: SELECT [Key], [Value] FROM [Properties]

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: Invalid object name 'Properties'.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource 1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Yup, the client I was working with had accidently mapped their old analytics database as the SXP8 Reporting database generating this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This agent uses the database referenced by the `reporting` connection string. Check if you see a `Properties` table in this database. If the table is missing, you can create it with this SQL statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Properties](
    [PropertyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Key] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [ntext] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PropertyId] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

A missing table may indicate that there are more incorrect things. Solving this *may* popup other errors. Make sure you have executed all steps when you performed the upgrade, especially those related to databases.

If the table is there, make sure the user defined in the connection string has access to it. You can test this by signing in with a SQL client (e.g. MS SQL Management Studio) with the username and password from the `reporting` connection string. Try to execute the select statement from the error.

Comment: The client I was working with had mapped their old analytics database as the connection string for the new reporting database. Resulting in the properties table being missing.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be so quick to arbitrarily create tables in databases. If it's a Sitecore database, and a table is missing there's probably a bigger issue at stake.

Comment: We had the same issue at one of the clients, although it was not Sitecore upgrade but new 8.1 update 3 implementation. We worked without Analytics almost till the go live, but for some strange reason, after installing MongoDB and configuring everything we had (I think) 3 missing tables. One of them was Properties and we executed the script above. After that the problems have disappeared. 

What you can do is to do a database backup and perform the script to see how it will behave for a test scenario.